# India Germany national visa - guest scholar/scientist

Tags: indian-citizens, germany

Dear learned colleagues,

I am an Indian and am an independent researcher. While I have published a lot of books (with standard scientific publishing houses) I don’t hold a job in an university and am away from academia. My highest qualification is an engineering in electronics.

I have been elected for a prestigious “fellowship” from Germany. It is fully funded including the sufficient stipend. But I am not able to decide the category of visa I should go for. Websites are confusing me more.

I should be applying for guest scientist/visiting scholar visa and have all the documents ready. But I do not have a NOC from my university since I don’t work for one.

Should I go ahead with this?

Visa office can’t apparently help me decide the category.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you asked the institution that has offered you the ‘fellowship’ for their advice? One would assume they might have experienced this situation before. How long are you expecting to be in Germany?

Comment: @Traveller: They told student visa or Guest scientist/visiting scholar visa. Ambiguous again! Thank you for your comment!

Comment: A NOC is typically required because it shows that the applicant has a compelling reason to return home at the end of their intended stay. If you can’t provide a NOC, what alternative documentation can you provide that might demonstrate this?

Comment: @Traveller: Fair enough! The only other documentation I have is the aeroplane tickets booked back to India at the end of 6 months. Would this suffice? I am not sure. Thanks anyway for your kind help.